# How to use Kafka Listener Acknowledgement with asynchronous processing

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a use case were we use a kafka listener to feed an external system. The external system is using an asynchronous communication channel with callbacks. I am trying to feed the external system, and want to call ack() or nack() on the Acknowledgement class depending on the outcome. The external system can take a while to acknowledge, and I don't want to block sending the next batch while waiting for this.

This is working fine for the ack() case, but it is not allowed the call the nack() from the call back thread.

Our first reaction was to attempt to park the nack() call till the next invocation of the listener but then it becomes impossible nack() the last batch until new data arrives on the topic, which is also not acceptible.

Some sample code simulating the use cases:

```
@KafkaListener(
                id = CREATE_USERS_LISTENER_ID,
                topics = CREATE_USER_TOPIC,
                containerFactory = KafkaConstants.BATCH_FACTORY,
                autoStartup = "false"
        )
        void simpleAsyncCase(ConsumerRecords<String, CreateUser> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment ack) {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                int idx = 0;
                String last = "";

                // simulation of contacting external system with external failures
                Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, CreateUser>> recordIterator = consumerRecords.iterator();
                while (recordIterator.hasNext()) {
                    ConsumerRecord<String, CreateUser> consumerRecord = recordIterator.next();
                    last = KafkaCoreListenerIT.toString(consumerRecord);
                    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                        System.out.printf("XXXX Processing records %s at index %d%n", last, idx);
                        latch.countDown();
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("XXXX ask to NACK record %s at index %d%n", last, idx);
                        return idx;
                    }
                    idx++;
                }

                System.out.printf("XXXX ask to ACK to to record %s at index %d%n", last, idx);
                return null;
            }).whenComplete((nackIdx, t) -> {
                try {
                    if (t != null) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.printf("XXXX NACK the full batch%n");
                        ack.nack(0, Duration.ZERO); // !!!-> this is not allowed
                    } else if (nackIdx != null) {
                        System.out.printf("XXXX NACK record at index %d%n", nackIdx);
                        ack.nack(nackIdx, Duration.ZERO); // !!!-> this is not allowed
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("XXXX Acknowledge");
                        ack.acknowledge(); // !!! -> this is working fine
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                }
            });
        }
```

Tried with ackMode MANUAL, MANUAL_IMMEDIATE (while enable.auto.commit was false) and asyncAcks enabled/disabled.

The question is basically, is it possible to use the Acknowledgment feature asynchronously ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use `nack()` asynchronously.

Comment: If it is not possible to nack() asynchronously, then it sadly as well not possible to use it at all. Any failure reporting is not possible, no retries, ... It is only possible to use it asynchronously in use cases that would never fail, which are going to be rare or non-existing I fear.

Comment: It is not recommended to perform **any** async processing with Kafka due to the way offset commits work - it is better to achieve concurrency by increasing the partition count. Consider the following: we deliver records for offsets 0, 1, 2, 3; the app then acks offsets 2,3,1 and then nacks offset 0 - that will "undo" the acks for the previously ack'd records. It gets even more complicated if the app nacks multiple records from the same batch - best advice - just don't do it (async processing).

Comment: I understand, but being optimist, things will normally all get acknowledged. Nack stituation should be rare, and indeed would cause some re-processing. A limit of outstanding batches would mitigate that. I doubt that parallelism due to more partitions would solve our case. We have an up to 30 sec acknowledgement from the external system. I think the problem would just replicate itself over all Kafka partitions. Think our only option is to go parallel within partitions and take the reprocessing hit in case things fail.

Comment: Even streams, when configured at-least-once will by default only commit offsets once every 30 seconds. Any restart of the application will also result in up to 30 seconds of traffic that will be reprocessed.

Comment: Perhaps Kafka is the wrong technology for your use case.

Comment: @Gary Russell, according to the Spring Kafka documentation, since 2.8, it's possible to enable async commit and commit in any order with a risk of duplication - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ooo-commits. Nack is not possible. Isn't that (the nack) something the user wouldn't have to worry about due to the fact the error handling is already taking care of this (an exception will always prevent committing offsets...)?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments. Out of order commits is intended to cover a very narrow set of use cases; best practice is to **never** process records asynchronously; you cannot use `nack()` and all records must be acknowledged before the next batch will be fetched.